# Issues regarding java.lang.NumberFormatException

Tags: java, arrays

I am getting the a number format exception with my current code. I am not sure exactly what the issue is but I feel it is something quite minor so I am not going to go into too much detail as to what my code is "suppose to do" but you will probably be able to tell anyways.

To keep things short, the code which follows is intended to use a selection sort with a bunch of random numbers. I believe the format issue may have to do with the [] which surround the integers in the error message but I really have no idea. Error messages lead back to the line under the button which states:
            int array[] = {Integer.parseInt(list.toString())};
This makes sense because this is the declaration but, I am not sure how to prevent this issue from persisting.

Thanks for any input whatsoever and I apologies for any obvious mistakes, I am quite novice.

Here is the main body of my current code so far:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

public static void selectionSort(int[] a) {
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        int smallestValue = a[i];
        int smallestIndex = i;
        for(int j = i+1; j < a.length; j++) {
            if (smallestValue > a[j]) {
                smallestValue = a[j];
                smallestIndex = j;
            }
        }
        a[smallestIndex] = a[i];
        a[i] = smallestValue;
}
}

public void start() {
    int times = Integer.parseInt(n2sInput.getText());
    for (int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
        list.add(new Random().nextInt(2000) - 1000);
    }
}

public static String arrayToString(int[] a) {
    String result = "";
    for (int v : a) {
        result += v + " ";
    }
    return result;
}

private void sortButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           

    if(selButton.isSelected()) {
        start();
        int array[] = {Integer.parseInt(list.toString())};
        onOutput.setText(arrayToString(array));
        selectionSort(array);
        snOutput.setText(arrayToString(array));
    } else if(bubButton.isSelected()) {

    } else if(insButton.isSelected()) {

    } else if(quiButton.isSelected()) {

    }
}
```

Comment: List is an object and you can't simply convert it to a string, you have to iterate through the list to get every integer in it and then you can do whatever you want to with these.

Comment: `Integer.parseInt(list.toString())` this will try to parse the whole list to a single Integer which could be the reason of the problem. You want it like this(single int)? or you want each element in `string` list to be in your `int` array? @Natecurt3030

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error happens here:

```
int array[] = {Integer.parseInt(list.toString())};
```

This is because you convert a list to a string and then try to parse it. A list as a string cannot be parsed to an int. If you want to see why, try printing out `list.toString()`.

If you want to convert your list to an array, do this instead:

```
Integer[] array = list.toArray(new Integer[0]);
```

Comment: That will give you a class cast exception, surely. The list contains boxed Integers, not primitive ints.

Comment: Still no good: `[Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Integer`. To get the right kind of array you'd need to call `list.toArray(new Integer[0]);`

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang) to convert `List<Integer>` to `int[]`
as bellow:

```
int array[] = ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(list.toArray(new Integer[0]));
```